# How can I run Warcraft 3 on my new MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently bought the digital copies of Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos and Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne from the blizzard store. They are registered with my blizzard account but when I download the zip file it opens a downloader but my computer says it can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer. What can I do about this?

The error is shown in this image
[image: Error]

Comment: You can always run the Windows version from Boot Camp or a virtual machine.

Answer (score 5):

From https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/playing-older-blizzard-titles-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion :

> Warcraft III will only run on Mac OS X 10.7 if your operating system
>   was upgraded from 10.6.X and only if the Warcraft III installation was
>   patched before the operating system was upgraded. There is currently
>   no way to install or patch the game on Lion.

So you need a 10.6 system to bootstrap from.

Comment: The problem is that Rosetta - the emulator that ran old PowerPC programs - was discontinued in 10.7.  Personally I really wonder why, but most likely to be able to start migrating to new API's without having to support the old stuff.

Comment: One way to do it is to install the WC3 game on a Mac with 10.6 and patch it, then move the game files to your current system.

Comment: I've done this, but multiplayer doesn't work. It works under 10.6, so this leads me to believe that something is installed somewhere else. Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 3):

What this error box shows is the [Gatekeeper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html) functionality that notes if an application has not been signed by a developer registered with Apple.

It prevents people from accidentally running apps that are unsigned.

You can make this and only this application run by bypassing this gatekeeper check by opening  a Finder window showing the file and right click on the file and select open, you will then get a dialog box similar to the one you have which will also have an OK button allowing you to open the application.

You can also relax the settings in System Preferences to stop this check happening and allow any application to run (unlock and select the button named **Anywhere** and run all the unsigned apps you want to trust and then revert the settings to more secure)
[image]

---

However from other answers this might only get you a bit further as this does not deal with Rosetta/PowerPC issues.

Comment: I did what you said here and it let me download it but when it gets through downloading it nothing happens and i cant find where it has downloaded. any advice?

Comment: I would guess /Applications but if it uses a downloaded it is not likely to be standard OS X use. You could look in the smart folders in Finder and see what recently changed